# Background image issue with local images when i use bg in div

Tags: background, tailwind-css, web-deployment

[image]

[image]

I have a issue in tailwind css when i use bg-"[url('.assets/images.png')]" these is not working when i put online image address the image is coming what could be the issue with local images as i frustrated doing and doing but not  geeting any
solution

A explaination would be helpful and correct syntax would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is typo, `url` is outside the `[]`

Change

```
bg-url['(<imagepath)']
```

to

```
bg-[url('<imagepath>')]
```

---

##### Extra: Procedure:

When using asset image make sure you add your own background images by editing the **`theme.backgroundImage`** section of your **`tailwind.config.js`** file:

###### tailwind.config.cs

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'images': "url('.assets/images.png')",  add your image here
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### Then use it as

```
<div class="bg-[url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Refer: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image

Comment: We have to write in tailwind config part write then only it will work or what

Comment: Yes, right it in tailwind.config.cs and correct your typo errors, it will work for you. Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the syntax of tailwind css, but it looks like your path '.assets/images.png' is not valid because of the '.assets' part. Try to find out where your image are located in relation to your resulting css file.

If they are organized like

```
assets/
  images/
  css/
    styles.css
```

you can write

```
bg-"[url('../images/images.png')]"
```

If it's like

```
assets/
  images/
public/
  css/
    styles.css
```

you can write

```
bg-"[url('../../assets/images.png')]"
```

But as I said I don't know tailwind.

After seeing your Screenshot and the organization of your files I think that

`class= "bg-url[('Assets/images.png')]"`

will lead to success, because your assets folder is located in the same folder as your index.html and it seems a good idea to write the path inside the quotation marks, not the brackets.

Comment: As i have shared the screenshot of the path is that correct i have all the images in assets only it's ./assets

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't notice your screenshot. I only saw the error in bg-"[url('.assets/images.png')]". But the organization of your files make me think that 
`bg-"[url('assets/images.png')]"` will lead to success, because your assets folder is located in the same folder as your index.html.